# Nested JSON output from mongodb via Get

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have some status-Data from a bunch of devices stored in mongoDB and I like to aggregate via mongoose some simple statistics pending on input variables e.g. input about timespan (start to end).

Plane Dataset in mongoDB looks somehowe like this:

```
{
"_id":"5d65b4a9cef78a5c987b2224",
"Date":"2019-08-01T00:00:00.000Z",
"Id":9,
"StandingNoMovement":21.9,
"DrivingHours":0.4,
"StandingWithEngineOn":1.6
},
{
"_id":"5d65b4a9cef78a5c987b2225",
"Date":"2019-08-02T00:00:00.000Z",
"Id":9,
"StandingNoMovement":19.2,
"DrivingHours":2.3,
"StandingWithEngineOn":2.3,
}
```

and I need to create a GET for an API with the structure of

```
[{"Id":9,
"DrivingHours":
{"Total":276.9,"Day":0.0,"ThisWeek":0.0,"ThisMonth":0.0},
"StandingNoMovement":
{"Total":678.4,"Day":0.0,"ThisWeek":0.0,"ThisMonth":0.0},
"StandingWithEngineOn":
{"Total":521.4,"Day":0.0,"ThisWeek":0.0,"ThisMonth":0.0}]
```

So fare, I only managed to aggregate some not nestet statistics in mongoose like:

```
const aggReport = mongoose.model('aggReport', aggReportingSchema);

aggReport.aggregate([
        { $match: 
            { Id : req.params.Id ,'Date': { $gte: start, $lt: end}
            }
        },
        { $group: 
            { _id: null, 
            'DrivingHours': {$sum: '$DrivingHours'},
            'StandingWithEngineOn': {$sum: '$StandingWithEngineOn'},
            'StandingNoMovement': {$sum: '$StandingNoMovement'}
            }
        }])
```

on the Schema

```
export const aggReportingSchema = new Schema({
    Id:{ type: Number},
    Date:{ type: Date},
    StandingNoMovement:{ type: Number},
    StandingWithEngineOn:{ type: Number},
    },{ collection : 'status_daily' });
```

How to get the nested statistics as they look that simple to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just switched now to a total different approach, as I got the impression, that there are no proper and usable solutions (perhaps with good reasons) to dynamically create such a API. So now I store all the date precalculated in the mondodb and I am using express and node just to call the necessary dataset.